# Nested If-else pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input dataframe `df`, where I want to transform column `A`...

```
A   B
    asd
0   dsf
1   ewr
2   dfds
3   sdf
```

...into my expected output `df1`:

```
        Aa  Ab  Ac              Bb
                                asd
        0   0   0               dsf
        1   0   0               ewr
        1   1   0               dfds
        1   1   1               sdf
```

Code:

```
if df['A'] == '' :
    df1['Aa'] = ''
elif df['A'] == 1 :
    df1['Aa'] == 1
elif df['A'] == 0 :
    df1['Aa'] == 0
else:
    df1['Aa'] == 1
```

Error:

```
if df['A'] == '' :                                                                                                                                                       
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__                                                                                              
    raise ValueError(                                                                                                                                                                        
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Similar formula in excel

```
 B2 =IF(A2=1,1,IF(A2="","",IF(A2=0,0,1)))
```

Similarly;

```
 C2 = IF(A2=2,1,IF(A2="","",IF(A2=0,0,1)))
```

Trying to achieve something similar with python. Please Help!!

Logic :

```
if value in df['A'] == ''; new column 'Aa,Ab,Ac' in df1 == ''
if value in df['A'] == 1; new column 'Aa' in df1 == 1, and rest (Ab,Ac) == 0
if value in df['A'] == 2; new column 'Aa, Ab' in df1== 1, and rest (Ac) == 0
if value in df['A'] == 3; new column 'Aa,Ab,Ac' in df1 == 1
```

So, the flow can be something like:

df1:

```
A   Aa  Ab  Ac              Bb
                            asd
0   0   0   0               dsf
1   1   0   0               ewr
2   1   1   0               dfds
3   1   1   1               sdf
```

Later just remove column `A`. So `Final df1`

```
        Aa  Ab  Ac              Bb
                                asd
        0   0   0               dsf
        1   0   0               ewr
        1   1   0               dfds
        1   1   1               sdf
```

Comment: Do the values in Aa, Ab, Ac actually depend on the original values in A beyond carrying the empty string value across the whole row? Or do you just want 1s and 0s arranged in this triangular pattern?

Comment: Have a look into the `numpy.where()` function. [Here are the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). It adds excellent 'if/then/else' logic to DataFrames.

Comment: Your input column `df.A` is numeric, so trying to do a string compare `df['A'] == ''` will also fail for that reason, as well as the issue you get with the output being a series not just a scalar.

Comment: Essentially you want to convert the 2-bit binary value in `df.A` into [binary-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) columns `[Aa,Ab,Ac]`. Although they're flipped left-to-right; normally encoding would start from the LSB, i.e. `Ac`.

Comment: @G.Anderson They do depend on A, this is just an example. In my dataset I have multiple 1s,2s and so on... based on another logic so `A` could be like  `0 0 0 0 1 1 3 2 2...` .
I have provided the logic that I need for calculation of Aa Ab Ac{random column names}, just can't determine how to code this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to do this, just put this inside a function, and you could use it for the other nested loops too

```
   conditions = [
        (df['A'] == 0),
        (df['A'] == 1),
        (df['A'] > 1)]
    choices = [0, 1, 1]
    df1['Aa'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='null')
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["",0,1,2,3]})
df['new_a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')
df['Aa'] = df['new_a'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if math.isnan(x) else (0 if x==0 else (OTHER CONDITION)))
```

you can use the similar logic to create your 'Ab', 'Ac', and 'Bb'

Comment: Oddly I am facing the same issue today, I have many nested loops so the solution proposed wont work....am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Similar situation as that of @El_1988, not sure this solution works for me

Comment: @RoshanShah22 I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237931/for-repeated-rows-in-column-of-nested-lists-in-dataframe-group-corresponding-ro , if a solution shows up will share here

Comment: Hey @El_1988, I tried something and it seems to work. Maybe give it a shot